# useEffect() hook is not triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

There is a problem I'm currently experiencing with. The `keysType` state value is set to `null` because it's being used for displaying other keyboard types. The thing is I want it to display the current keyboard on the first load by using `useEffect()` hook to append the `keysArray` variable. I am expecting that its value will be `keysArray` but it keeps the default value which is `null`. So that's why the browser throws the error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'keysType.map')
```

Does our community has a solution to this problem?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BsArrowReturnLeft, BsGlobe2, BsShift, BsShiftFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { GoSmiley } from "react-icons/go";
import { IoBackspaceOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

export default function Keyboard(){
    const keysArray = [
        // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'],
        // ['-', '/', ':', ';', '(', ')', '$', '&', '@', '"'],
        // ['#+=', '.', ',', '?', '!', '\'', 'backspace'],
        ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'],
        ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
        ['caps', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'backspace'],
        ['num', 'lang', 'emoji', 'space', 'return']
    ];

    const [keysType, setKeysType] = useState(null);
    const [caps, setCaps] = useState(false);
    const [num, setNum] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setKeysType(keysArray);
    }, []);

    const Key = ({ children, className }) => {
        return (
            <div className={twMerge('flex justify-center items-center w-10 bg-gray-800/30 py-3 px-1 rounded-md m-[3px] text-gray-100 transition-all duration-200 active:bg-gray-700/40 active:transition-none', className)}>
                {children}
            </div>
        )
    }

    function generate(key){
        switch(key){
            case 'backspace':
                return (
                    <Key className='w-[54px]'>
                        <IoBackspaceOutline/>
                    </Key>
                )
            case 'caps':
                return (
                    <Key className='w-[54px]'>
                        {caps ? <BsShiftFill/> : <BsShift/>}
                    </Key>
                )
            case 'num':
                return (
                    <Key className='text-sm w-9'>
                        <p>{num ? 'ABC' : '123'}</p>
                    </Key>
                )
            case 'emoji':
                return (
                    <Key className='w-8'>
                        <GoSmiley/>
                    </Key>
                )
            case 'lang':
                return (
                    <Key className='w-8'>
                        <BsGlobe2/>
                    </Key>
                )
            case 'space':
                return (
                    <Key className='w-52'></Key>
                )
            case 'return':
                return (
                    <Key className='w-28'>
                        <BsArrowReturnLeft/>
                    </Key>
                )
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='absolute bottom-0 z-10 bg-gray-900/90 backdrop-blur p-1 pb-12 w-full'>
            <div className="flex flex-col">
                {keysType.map(keys => (
                    <div className="flex justify-center w-full">
                        {keys.map(key => (
                            <>
                                {generate(key)}
                            </>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: as an alternative to the answer, you simply could write `const [keysType, setKeysType] = useState(keysArray);` and get rid of the `useEffect`, which at this point is totally useless. Doing so, the rest of your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is related to the asynchronous nature of the useEffect hook. The initial render of the component occurs before the effect is executed, so the keysType state is still null when the component tries to map over it. To fix this issue, you can conditionally render the mapping part of the component only when keysType is not null. Here's an updated version of your code with the necessary changes:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BsArrowReturnLeft, BsGlobe2, BsShift, BsShiftFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { GoSmiley } from "react-icons/go";
import { IoBackspaceOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

export default function Keyboard() {
  const keysArray = [
    // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'],
    // ['-', '/', ':', ';', '(', ')', '$', '&', '@', '"'],
    // ['#+=', '.', ',', '?', '!', '\'', 'backspace'],
    ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p"],
    ["a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l"],
    ["caps", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "backspace"],
    ["num", "lang", "emoji", "space", "return"],
  ];

  const [keysType, setKeysType] = useState(null);
  const [caps, setCaps] = useState(false);
  const [num, setNum] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setKeysType(keysArray);
  }, []);

  const Key = ({ children, className }) => {
    return (
      <div
        className={twMerge(
          "flex justify-center items-center w-10 bg-gray-800/30 py-3 px-1 rounded-md m-[3px] text-gray-100 transition-all duration-200 active:bg-gray-700/40 active:transition-none",
          className
        )}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };

  function generate(key) {
    switch (key) {
      case "backspace":
        return (
          <Key className="w-[54px]">
            <IoBackspaceOutline />
          </Key>
        );
      case "caps":
        return (
          <Key className="w-[54px]">
            {caps ? <BsShiftFill /> : <BsShift />}
          </Key>
        );
      case "num":
        return (
          <Key className="text-sm w-9">
            <p>{num ? "ABC" : "123"}</p>
          </Key>
        );
      case "emoji":
        return (
          <Key className="w-8">
            <GoSmiley />
          </Key>
        );
      case "lang":
        return (
          <Key className="w-8">
            <BsGlobe2 />
          </Key>
        );
      case "space":
        return <Key className="w-52"></Key>;
      case "return":
        return (
          <Key className="w-28">
            <BsArrowReturnLeft />
          </Key>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="absolute bottom-0 z-10 bg-gray-900/90 backdrop-blur p-1 pb-12 w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {keysType !== null &&
          keysType.map((keys, index) => (
            <div className="flex justify-center w-full" key={index}>
              {keys.map((key) => (
                <React.Fragment key={key}>{generate(key)}</React.Fragment>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: or even a shorter `keysType && keysType.map(( ...`